# Linq query to transform data into timeseries

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I have the following data:

```
10/6/2018 - Category 1
11/6/2018 - Category 1
12/6/2018 - Category 2
13/6/2018 - Category 1
15/6/2018 - Category 3
20/7/2018 - Category 1
21/7/2018 - Category 1
4/8/2018 - Category 4
5/8/2018 - Category 2
```

I'm trying to use linq in dot net core in order to get a json result that I can chart.  I'm trying to do a graph which groups the count by month.

The result should look like this (the categories are dynamic, I can't hard code them):

```
series: [{
  name: 'Category 1',
  data: [3, 2, 0]
}, {
  name: 'Category 2',
  data: [1, 0, 1]
}, {
  name: 'Category 3',
  data: [1, 0, 0]
}, {
  name: 'Category 4',
  data: [0, 0, 1]
}]
```

I'm not sure where to start, how would I do this in dot net core with linq

Edit based on comments:

Firstly the data is coming from a database, so it's dynamic.  Secondly the result is what I want my output to be, ie, Category 1 has 2 items in June, 2 items in July, and 0 in August (I'm using DD/MM/YYYY in case that's not clear)

Comment: How do you get those values for the dates? Also what have you tried?

Comment: Where does the data array come from (e.g. `data: [2, 2, 0]`)

Comment: I've updated my question - I haven't really tried anything, I've done some research and thing I need to GroupBy the Category but not sure if this is correct or how to do it

Comment: Does your data have typo??? How does Category 1 have [2,2,0]? It has 3 entries in June, no?

Comment: Category 1 has 3 items in June :)

Comment: You would need a `GroupBy ` for Category and month/year (and a `Count` of the month/year)

Comment: Also if it is dynamic, how come you know array with 3 elements mean June, July, August entries?

Comment: Bah you're right, 3 items in June, I've fixed the typo!

Comment: @CetinBasoz The query that I would run in the database would be to go back on the last 3 months, so I would need a count for each of the last 3 months

Comment: That last comment is details that should be in the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NewtonSoft.Json to get that as a JSON:

```
void Main()
{
    var myData = new List<MyClass> {
        new MyClass {Date=new DateTime(2018,6,10),Category="Category 1"},
        new MyClass {Date=new DateTime(2018,6,11),Category="Category 1"},
        new MyClass {Date=new DateTime(2018,6,12),Category="Category 2"},
        new MyClass {Date=new DateTime(2018,6,13),Category="Category 1"},
        new MyClass {Date=new DateTime(2018,6,15),Category="Category 3"},
        new MyClass {Date=new DateTime(2018,7,20),Category="Category 1"},
        new MyClass {Date=new DateTime(2018,7,21),Category="Category 1"},
        new MyClass {Date=new DateTime(2018,8,4),Category="Category 4"},
        new MyClass {Date=new DateTime(2018,8,5),Category="Category 2"},
    };


    var result = from c in myData.Select(d => d.Category).Distinct()
                 let months = myData.Select(d => d.Date.Month).Distinct().OrderBy(d => d).ToArray()
                 let m1 = months[0]
                 let m2 = months[1]
                 let m3 = months[2]
                 select new {
                     name = c,
                     data = new int[] {
                        myData.Count(d => d.Category == c && d.Date.Month==m1),
                        myData.Count(d => d.Category == c && d.Date.Month==m2),
                        myData.Count(d => d.Category == c && d.Date.Month==m3),
                     }
                 };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    Console.WriteLine(@"""series"": " + json);
}

public class MyClass
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```